# How to determine maximum required alignment in C99

Tags: c, c99, memory-alignment

Is there a portable way that only relies on what the C99 standard provides to find out the maximum required alignment that is needed for any data type.

Like `maxalign_t` in C++11.

What I'm currently doing is calculating the least common multiple (`lcm`) of the alignments of `int`, `long int`, `long long int`, `double`, `void *` and `size_t` as best effort way of determining the alignment.

**Update:**
I currently need this for implementing a wrapper around `malloc` that stores metadata at the beginning of the block of memory and returns a pointer with a higher address than what `malloc` has returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really a good way to do that, which is why `maxalign_t` was introduced by C11. Though, I cannot imagine an ordinary system where a type with higher alignment requirements than `intmax_t` exists so you might as well use that and get the right answer for 99% of the systems when `maxalign_t` is not available.

Comment: Sad to hear that. I'll evaluate if it is possible to switch to C11 otherwise use intmax_t.

Comment: To be even more paranoid you could use the alignment requirement of `intmax_t` or `long double`, whichever is greater.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Don't forget `void*`.  A 128-bit pointer type could combine information about base address, size, and offset, allowing erroneous pointer manipulations to be trapped much more effectively than would be possible using simple linear pointers.

Comment: @FSMaxB Updating my previous comment: To be really paranoid you could use the maximum alignment requirement of `intmax_t`, `long double`, `void *`, and `void (*)()` (that is, of the largest integral, largest floating-point, generic data pointer, and function pointer types).

Comment: @SteveSummit: Would that really take care of things?  I don't think anything would forbid a compiler from requiring that, for at least some types, a T[N] would have a coarser alignment requirement than a T for even values of N (such an alignment requirement would not affect the size or stride of any array, except that certain structs containing an array would be bigger.  I think it would be very useful to have a testable standard macro via which a compiler could assert that arrays have the same alignment as the underlying element, but at present there's no means via which programs...

Comment: ...can indicate that they rely upon such behaviors.

Comment: @supercat It's very likely that it does. I doubt there is a better way, especially one that is portable.

Comment: What about `__m128` and all their lot?

Comment: @ach 128 bit ints are confusing me too. Can't align to `long double` or any of the above suggestions because those have 8 byte requirements where a 128 bit int would have a 16 byte one.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the maximum supported alignment empirically by allocating several chunks and seeing if each chunk is aligned on a 16, 8, or 4 byte boundary.

```
bool GetConsistentAlignment( std::size_t alignment )
{
    const unsigned int chunkCount = 16;
    void * places[ chunkCount ];
    memset( places, 0, sizeof(places) );
    bool consistent = true;

    for ( unsigned int ii = 0;  ii < chunkCount; ++ii )
    {
        const std::size_t size = 1024 + rand() % 4096;
        void * chunk = malloc( size );
        places[ ii ] = chunk;
    }

    for ( unsigned int ii = 0;  ii < chunkCount; ++ii )
    {
        void * chunk = places[ ii ];
        const std::size_t place = reinterpret_cast< const std::size_t >( chunk );
        if ( place % alignment != 0 )
        {
            consistent = false;
        }
        free( chunk );
    }

    return consistent;
}

std::size_t GetMaxSupportedAlignment()
{
    static std::size_t maxAlignment = 0;

    if ( maxAlignment == 0 )
    {
        std::srand( std::time( 0 ) );
        std::size_t alignment = 64;
        while ( alignment > 1 )
        {
            const bool isConsistentAlignment = GetConsistentAlignment( alignment );
            if ( isConsistentAlignment )
            {
                break;
            }
            alignment /= 2;
        }
        maxAlignment = alignment;
    }

    return maxAlignment;
}
```

Calling `GetMaxSupportedAlignment()` will return 8 on 64-bit operating systems and 4 on many 32-bit systems.

Comment: This is not really a practical solution, more like an esoteric one. Your approach is probabilistic, it is not guaranteed to always produce the same result. Also it relies on heap allocations (not too nice) and it is actually C++, not C99.